# Objective-c SBJSONWriter convert array of dictionaries to JSON

Tags: objective-c, json, sbjson

I'm having some trouble with SBJsonWriter at the moment.

I need to send a request that contains a json object of name/value pairs. e.g.

```
[{%22uid%22:1,%22version%22:1}]
```

I can't figure out how to do this in Obj-C with the SBJson Writer framework.

For each pair I have tried to construct a dictionary then add the dictionary to an array. This results in an array containing many dictionaries, each containing one name/value pair.

Any idea on how a fix for this or is it possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of creating a dictionary **for each** name-value pair, create a dictionary that contains **all** name-value pairs of a given object. In your example, it’d be one dictionary containing two name-value pairs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To produce an Objective-C structure equivalent to the above JSON you should do this:

```
NSArray* json = [NSArray arrayWithObject: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: 
                                               [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1], @"uid",
                                               [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1], @"version",
                                               nil]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Check my answer to the '' [SBJsonWriter Nested NSDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11765037/sbjsonwriter-nested-nsdictionary/12383548#12383548) '' question. it illustrates how to properly use SBJsonWriter.

It includes error check and some pieces of advise about SBJsonWriter behaviour with NSDate, float, etc..

Excerpt:

```
NSDictionary* aNestedObject = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                      @"nestedStringValue", @"aStringInNestedObject",
                                      [NSNumber numberWithInt:1], @"aNumberInNestedObject",
                                 nil];

NSArray * aJSonArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"arrayItem1", @"arrayItem2", @"arrayItem3", nil];

NSDictionary * jsonTestDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                     @"stringValue", @"aString",
                                     [NSNumber numberWithInt:1], @"aNumber",
                                     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.2345f], @"aFloat",
                                     [[NSDate date] description], @"aDate",
                                     aNestedObject, @"nestedObject",
                                     aJSonArray, @"aJSonArray",
                                     nil];
```