# SBJsonWriter Nested NSDictionary

Tags: json, nsdictionary, sbjson

I'm trying to serialize an objc object with Json to send it to a server.

That same server sends the following on GET for this object type:

```
 {
   "TypeProperties":[
      {"Key":"prop 0","Value":"blah 0"},
      {"Key":"prop 1","Value":"blah 1"},
      {"Key":"prop 2","Value":"blah 2"},
      {"Key":"prop 3","Value":"blah 3"}
     ],
   "ImageURls":[
      {"Key":"url 0","Value":"blah 0"},
      {"Key":"url 1","Value":"blah 1"},
      {"Key":"url 2","Value":"blah 2"},
      {"Key":"url 3","Value":"blah 3"}
     ]
}
```

SBJsonWriter produces the following for the matching object/type that I've created in objc:

```
{
  "TypeProperties": {
    "key 2": "object 2",
    "key 1": "object 1",
    "key 4": "object 4",
    "key 0": "object 0",
    "key 3": "object 3"
  },
  "ImageUrls": {
    "key 0": "url 0",
    "key 1": "url 1",
    "key 2": "url 2"
  }
}
```

This is how I'm using SBJsonWriter:

```
SBJsonWriter *writer = [[SBJsonWriter alloc] init];
writer.humanReadable = YES;
NSString* json = [writer stringWithObject:itemToAdd];
```

Here's my implementation of proxyForJson in the class being serialized (required by SBJsonWriter):

```
- (NSDictionary*) proxyForJson
{
      return [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                self.typeProperties, @"TypeProperties",
                self.imageUrls, @"ImageUrls",
                nil];
}
```

The class being serialized contains only the two properties: typeProperties and imageUrls (both are NSMutableDictionary).

Now, the problem: the server (not surprisingly) does not parse the Json produced by SBJsonWriter when I perform a POST. And the question: how do I produce Json that matches that which is provided by the server (assuming that matching Json would be parsed correctly on upload).

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JSON, `{ }` represents an object (key/value pairs) and `[ ]` represents an array. Judging by the sample you provided, here's what your server expects:

**Top Object**: dictionary with two keys: `TypeProperties` and `ImageUrls`.

**TypeProperties** and **ImageUrls**: each is an array containing one or more objects with two keys: `Key` and `Value`. Each key should have its respective value.

To comply with what your server expects, you need a structure similar to this (note this is just a bare example, written directly here, but should point you in the right direction):

```
NSDictionary *object = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        @"prop 0", @"Key",
                        @"blah 0", @"Value",
                        nil];

NSArray *typeProperties = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           object, // Add as many similar objects as you want
                           nil];

NSArray *imageUrls = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                      object, // Add as many similar objects as you want
                      nil];
```

Then, in your `proxyForJson` method, you can use:

```
- (NSDictionary*) proxyForJson
{
      return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
              typeProperties, @"TypeProperties",
              imageUrls, @"ImageUrls",
              nil];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple code demonstrating how to use SBJsonWriter:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import "SBJsonWriter.h"


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        NSDictionary* aNestedObject = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                              @"nestedStringValue", @"aStringInNestedObject",
                                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:1], @"aNumberInNestedObject",
                                         nil];

        NSArray * aJSonArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"arrayItem1", @"arrayItem2", @"arrayItem3", nil];

        NSDictionary * jsonTestDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                             @"stringValue", @"aString",
                                             [NSNumber numberWithInt:1], @"aNumber",
                                             [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.2345f], @"aFloat",
                                             [[NSDate date] description], @"aDate",
                                             aNestedObject, @"nestedObject",
                                             aJSonArray, @"aJSonArray",
                                             nil];

        // create JSON output from dictionary

        NSError *error = nil;
        NSString * jsonTest = [[[SBJsonWriter alloc] init] stringWithObject:jsonTestDictionary error:&error];

        if ( ! jsonTest ) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }else{
            NSLog(@"%@", jsonTest);
        } 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

outputs

```
{
    "aDate":"2012-09-12 07:39:00 +0000",
    "aFloat":1.2345000505447388,
    "nestedObject":{
        "aStringInNestedObject":"nestedStringValue",
        "aNumberInNestedObject":1
     },
    "aJSonList":["arrayItem1","arrayItem2","arrayItem3"],
    "aString":"stringValue",
    "aNumber":1
}
```

Notes:

1. Using 'error' allowed me to figure out that if you write [NSDate
   date] instead of [[NSDate date] description] you will get a "JSON
   serialisation not supported for
   __NSTaggedDate" error.
2. notice the float rounding error... 1.2345 became 1.2345000505447388

Comment: nice one.. its really a DEMO cum life saver :-)