# URL for GET request

Tags: ios, json, get

To get the JSON I was using this answer [SBJsonWriter Nested NSDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11765037/sbjsonwriter-nested-nsdictionary/12383548#12383548)

Now I have a sting `{"key1":"bla1","key2":{"a":"a1","b":"b1","c":"c1","d":"d1"},"key3":"bla3"}` that I've called `theString`
and I need to add it to a url `http://mysyte.net:8888/JSON?`
and to receive something like this `http://lcwebtest.sytes.net:8888/JSON?{"key1":"bla1","key2":{"a":"a1","b":"b1","c":"c1","d":"d1"},"key3":"bla3"}`

Here is what I do:
`NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://mysyte.net:8888/JSON?%@",theString];`

NSLog gives `http://mysyte.net:8888/JSON?{"key2":{"d":"d1","b":"b1","c":"c1","a":"a1"},"key1":"bla1","key3":"bla3"}`

Then I make a url from it by
NSURL *url1 = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

BUT `NSLog(@"%@",url1);` gives me `{null}`

I assume NSURL does not want to read the "{" or "}" and thinks that the url was malformed.

How can I receive the url to make a GET request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I assume NSURL does not want to read the "{" or "}" and thinks that the url was malformed.

That's right, you're not allowed to put some special characters in a URL. You want to escape the JSON string like this:

```
CFStringRef escaped = CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
    NULL,
    (CFStringRef)theString, // (__bridge CFStringRef)theString if you use ARC
    CFSTR(""),
    CFSTR("?&=%,:+-"),
    kCFStringEncodingUTF8
);
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://mysyte.net:8888/JSON?%@", (NSString *)escaped];
CFRelease(escaped);
```